# Unusual result to the addition

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic

> Question: Prove that
>
> (666... to n digits)^2 + (888... to n digits)=(444... to 2n digits)

My way: I just proved the given equation for three values of n and written at the bottom.

"Since the equation satisfies for n=1, 2, and 3, the equation is true and hence proved."

Also I am seeing a regular pattern in (6666...to n digits)^2
$666^2=443556,6666^2=44435556,66666^2=4444355556$
So the pattern is first there are (n-1) $4's$ the one $3$ then (n-1) 5's the one 6.

Is there a general way to solve this question?

Comment: Because it's true for $n=1,2,3$ doesn't mean AT ALL that it's proved for any $n$

Comment: The formula $n^2+n+41$ gives a prime number for $n=1, 2, 3$. Therefore the formula gives a prime number for all $n$!

Comment: @symplectomorphic Insightful observation: considering these 3 numbers are different this could lead to a new proof of the infinity of primes. Screw Euclid!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question: Prove that
>
> $(666\dots \text{to $n$ digits})^2 + (888\dots \text{to $n$
> > digits})=(444\dots \text{to $2n$ digits})$

By dividing by $4$, this is equivalent to

\begin{align}
(333\dots \text{to $n$ digits})^2 
+ (222\dots \text{to $n$ digits})
&=(111\dots \text{to $2n$ digits})
\end{align}
Let $x=111\dots \text{to $n$ digits}$. Then
\begin{align}
(3x)^2+2x&=x\cdot 10^n+x
\\
9x^2+2x&=x\cdot 10^n+x
\\
x(9x+2)&=x\cdot 10^n+x
\\
x(9x+1+1)&=x\cdot 10^n+x
\\
x(10^n+1)&=x\cdot 10^n+x.
\end{align}

Answer (score 10):

Hint: $n$ digits of $6$ is equal to
$$
  \left(6\left(\frac{10^n-1}{9}\right)\right)^2 = \frac{4}{9}(10^n-1)^2
     = \frac{4}{9}(10^{2n}-2\cdot 10^n+1).$$
Apply a similar transformation to the term with $8$'s, then see if you can simplify the sum.

Comment: But how did you thought about this transformation ,or other way around how did this came to your mind,i am surely trying your way.

Comment: Well, one recognizes $666...66$ as a multiple of $111...11$, and similarly with the others. The easiest way to write down the number $111...11$ is as I did it, as $(10^n-1)/9$. I'm not sure that helps you see how I thought of it; perhaps it's just having seen multiple problems like this. But you should always be looking for ways to rewrite a problem that introduce some regularity, such as all three of the terms here being multiples of $111...11$.

Comment: @rogerl It's worth noting that that expression for a sequence of 1s can be found as an application of the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series.

Comment: @MarkS: ... and the same for a sequence of 6's

Comment: @MarkS. Sure; I figured that the approach above would be easier to compute with and also easier for the OP to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Every time starting with $66^2$ adds another 4 to the beginning and a five between the 3 and 6. Also, the number of eights is half the length of $6666...^2$.

If this pattern continues, there are (n-1) 4's, a three, (n-1) five's, and finally a six. Because you add n 8's, the number becomes n 4's.